# Spacing in subject line for PHP mail() function

Tags: php, email

Does anyone know how to put a space for the subject line in between echo-ing a variable and the string itself using the php mail()? I have tried this

```
$subject = $user_data->first .' '.'recommends a place';
```

and this

```
$subject = $user_data->first .' recommends a place';
```

But when the mail is send, it displays **'Kevinrecommends a place'**.

Here's the full mail code:

```
$to = $form_input['email'];
$subject = $user_data->first .'&nbsp; recommends a place on';


$msg = 
    'Hi,'."\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    'You were recommended a place by '.$user_data->first .'.'."\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    'Click the link to see it on **!'."\r\n".
    'www.**.com/'.$token."\r\n".
    "\r\n".
    'Cheers,'
    $from = 'From:noreply@**.com';


mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
```

Comment: use &nbsp; for spacing and let me now if it fixes or not

Comment: Maybe this is just crazy talk, but why not do: `$subject = $user_data->first . ' recommends a place';`

Comment: i did, but it didn't work so i tried this also.

Comment: How about `$subject="$user_data->first recommends a place";` ?

Comment: @swapnesh, its displaying ***Kevin&nbsprecommends a place***. I used &nbsp inside quotes like this: `$subject = $user_data->first ."&nbsp".'recommends a place';` and like this `$subject = $user_data->first .'&nbsp recommends a place';`

Comment: Show us the PHP code used to send your mail.

Comment: @Jocelyn, its above now.

Comment: What does `var_dump($user_data->first);` give you?

Comment: @John3136, that doesn't work. it displays the literal string '$user_data->first' and not the variable.

Comment: @user1555300 its not &nbsp its &nbsp;   <--- with a semi colon..try this and let me know then

Comment: @swapnesh, with the semicolon, it doesn't work as well. `$subject = $user_data->first . '&nbsp;'. 'recommends a place';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$subject = "{$user_data->first} recommends a place";
```

Note the double quotes around the text. They are necessary to be sure `$user_data->first` gets interpreted.

Comment: sorry that doesn't work as well. Same string (no-space) shown in the subject line in my email... Is this just me?

Comment: okay, maybe i just change the wording this for now until i figure it out later. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = $user_data->first . ' recommends a place';
```

This should work perfectly fine. Now, I've sometimes had problems with weird Unicode characters. Are you sure the `$user_data->first` variable contains only letters?

Try this (don't leave it like this though, it'll delete all non-letter characters from your string):

```
$name = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/', '', $user_data->first);
$subject = $name . ' recommends a place';
```

Comment: Why are you suggesting to remove characters like éâäîåñ from the firstname? These are perfectly valid characters for a firstname.

Comment: @cambraca $user_data->first contains only letters and they have been filtered and preg_replace when the user registered

Comment: @Jocelyn I clearly stated they shouldn't leave it like that. This code is only for testing a specific case and see if something is wrong with that particular string.

Comment: @cambraca: OK. For testing purpose it's fine.